# Minimal of Ring Theory for Field/Galois theory.

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, field-theory

I am an undergraduate in my last semester, and due to bureaucratic reasons I couldn't take a course in Ring Theory until now. Again, for bureaucracy, I had to enroll in a course in Field theory and Galois theory this quarter, and I will be taking the Rings course in the next one. Not the ideal situation, I know, but that's how things ended up being and I won't be able to change the order in which I will take the courses (I tried to). So, I need to know what's the basic results of Ring theory I should be at least know to enunciate/or know the proofs in order to follow this course in field theory, as I listened that it is a very deep subject and I'm concerned about my ability to survive it. I didn't took the course in Ring theory but studied something by myself in the last month, so I know the language of homomorphisms, polynomial rings and the abstract Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I would like to know what exactly is demanded. Also, which book is a good reference to study field theory in a first course, given the present situation?

Comment: Fields are much simpler than rings in some sense, so as long as the course in field theory doesn't assume ring theory, you shouldn't have much of a problem anyway

Comment: Any good algebra book will do: Dummit&Foote, ,Hungerford, Artin...and mull over the possibility to change university: too much bureaucracy and what you do now is like trying to study multiplication before knowing what addition is. Focus mainly on Polynomial rings.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg How could a course in Field and Galois theory **not** assume ring theory? That sounds basically impossible...or a trashy course.

Comment: @DonAntonio I just mean that.. one could pick it up along the way!

Comment: To get a basic but decent understanding of Galois theory, the big things from ring theory are the isomorphism theorems and quotient rings (you'll often need to consider quotients like $F[x]/\langle f \rangle$ ).  Also be familiar with maximal & prime ideals (and ideals in general).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The question is really duplicate, and the first one has satisfactory answers. Should I delete mine then?